# How can I remove metadata from a flv file?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, flv

with ffmpeg I can use the command below to remove the metadata in General section

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c copy -metadata description= -metadata title= output.flv
```

[image]

What if I want to remove the metadata in Video and Audio section?

EDIT:
I want to remove writing library

[image]

Comment: Which metadata entries do you wish to remove?

Comment: @Gyan I want to remove writing library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FFmpeg v4.0 or newer, for your particular case,

```
ffmpeg -i in -c copy -bitexact -map_metadata -1 -vbsf filter_units=remove_types=6 out
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you explain the command? which part remove the 'writing library'? because I did not see 'writing library' in this command, what if I want to remove other entry in video or audio section?

Comment: `-vbsf filter_units=remove_types=6` removes the writing library for AVC video **only**. For different codecs, different commands apply. `-bitexact -map_metadata -1` gets rid of most metadata in general.